# Can the Hil Colish (Ghosts of Creuss Flagship) move through it's own wormhole in TI4?

Tags: twilight-imperium, twilight-imperium-4th-edition

The Hil Colish has the ability.

> This ship's system contains a delta wormhole. During movement, this ship may move before or after your other ships.

Can the Hil Colish use it's own wormhole (such as to retreat back to your home system)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can.

While this has not been addressed specifically for TI 4th edition, the answer appears to be yes by comparing 4th edition to 3rd edition.  In 3rd edition, the flagship had the ability:

> You may treat this ship's system as if it had a "D" Wormhole in it.  When this ship is moving, treat its destination system as if it had the Wormhole.

The third edition FAQ clarified:

> A system containing Hil Colish is considered to have a “D” Wormhole. While moving, only the destination system (the system activated), not the Flagship’s current system, is considered to have the “D” Wormhole. This system may only be considered a destination system if the Hil Colish will end its movement in the activated system. The Hil Colish cannot use the “D” Wormhole it generates.

Notice that 4th edition solved the problem of the Hil Colish moving quite differently, namely by having it move before or after your other ships so that other ships can use the wormhole.  The result of this is that the system containing the Hil Colish has a delta wormhole when it begins its movement, and follows the rules for wormholes, namely:

> Systems that contain identical wormholes are adjacent